# Android Kotlin DialogFragment (TimePicker)

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having problems showing a DialogFragment with Android in Kotlin. This is what I got so far:

The `TimePickerFragment.kt`

```
package de.flokol120.UniversalSleepTimer

import android.app.Dialog
import android.app.DialogFragment
import android.widget.TimePicker
import android.app.TimePickerDialog
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.format.DateFormat
import java.util.*


/**
 * @author flokol120
 * TimePicker Fragment to get the time
 */
class TimePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Dialog {
        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        return TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()))
    }

    override fun onTimeSet(view: TimePicker, hourOfDay: Int, minute: Int) {
        //TODO add this
    }
}
```

and the `AddTimer.kt`

```
package de.flokol120.UniversalSleepTimer

import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button


/**
 * @author flokol120
 * the fragment which adds a simple kill Timer
 */
class AddTimer : Fragment() {

    lateinit var timePicker : Button

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val v = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_timer, container, false)

        timePicker = v.findViewById(R.id.timePicker)

        timePicker.setOnClickListener {
            val newFragment = TimePickerFragment()
            newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "timePicker")
        }

        return v
    }

}
```

I also tried replacing the `fragmentManager` with `this@AddTimer.fragmentManager` but this doesn't seem to be the solution.

I am pretty clueless now because Android Studio says I have to use an `FragmentManager!` as first parameter but I am using one, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Aliaksandr Kavalenka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7697901/aliaksandr-kavalenka) came up with a neat workaround, which was for a date picker. I formatted his idea to work with a time picker:

```
fun getTime(textView: TextView, context: Context){

    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()

    val timeSetListener = TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener { timePicker, hour, minute ->
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour)
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)

        textView.text = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(cal.time)
    }

    textView.setOnClickListener {
        TimePickerDialog(context, timeSetListener, cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE), true).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe that helps you

I have a function **getDate()**

```
fun getDate(textView: TextView, context: Context){

        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()

        val dateSetListener = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)

            textView.text = SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(cal.time)

        }

        textView.setOnClickListener {
            DatePickerDialog(context, dateSetListener,
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show()
        }
    }
```

If an Activity need call DatePickerDialog - I simply use my function

```
presenter.getDate(textViewTime, this)
```

presenter - it is object where is my function getDate

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I wanted a Time Picker, not a Date Picker. But there is a TimePickerDialog too, which I could use, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing Regular DialogFragment with Support Lib Fragment.
You should extend "android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment" instead of "import android.app.DialogFragment".

Support lib uses support library version FragmentManager not regular Fragment Manager.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You! The error is gone but both `newFragment.show(this@AddTimer.fragmentManager, "timePicker")` and `newFragment.show(fragmentManager, "timePicker")` produces a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter savedInstanceState`. Any idea for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private var date: DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener? = null

 date = DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->

            myCalendar?.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
            myCalendar?.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear)
            myCalendar?.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
            val myFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.getDefault())
            Log.d("date_of_birth", sdf.format(myCalendar?.time))

        }
```